# Checkbox state style in gridview when focus is lost

Tags: gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using devexpress 14.2. In grid control (gridview) I have used a checkbox column. The column works well in input state in bind datasource, but my problem is with the visual state of the checkbox.

When the form loads, the checkbox state is shown as grayed-out (a solid blue square). When the cell of checkbx is focused, I can set the checkbox state as true or false (the stated value is correctly reflected in the datatable).

However, when the focus of the checkbox cell is lost and the focus transfers to the next cell, the visual style of the checkbox is reverted to the previous style (a solid square), although the value is correctly reflected in datatable and it is not changed.

How can I configure the check box column to show the real state of the checkbox?

[image]

NOTE: in the above picture, the current state of the first row checkbox is checked (true), the second row is unchecked (false). The correct state is only shown in the third row which is focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by following procedure:

The `ColumnEdit` property in the grid view must not be set as `RepositoryItemCheckedEdit`. The `ColumnEdit` must be none and for showing the checkbox in that column, the data type of corresponding column in datatable must be specified as boolean.

Just that simple.